# League of Legends in Xubuntu 16.04.1 keeps crashing while updating

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, games, playonlinux

I was an avid League of Legends (LoL) player when I was using windows, but my PC became so obsolete that in order for it to work I had to get (X)ubuntu on it.
I have quite a setup on linux now and I can do almost everything I did on Windows but playing LoL isn't one of those things. I installed LoL using the playonlinux method and it worked perfectly. But when i launched it, the update stopped at 38% (2/2) and after half an hour the client crashed and asked me if I wanted to send a bug report... This happened to me everytime I tried to do the update, always stopping at 37/38 %.

Does anybody have the same problem?

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Should I just try Dota 2 and forget LoL ?

Thank you, Francisco Castro

Answer (score 0):

What work for me in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS as of patch 6.22 was changing settings of LoL launcher through PlayonLinux.

1.Install the most recent version of PlayonLinux and install the League of Legends. (Do not start game after installation)

2. Using PlayonLinux access the LoL game settings.
3. In PlayonLinux change the default wine version using the "General" tab.From 1.9.2 LeagueofLegends5 to the latest stagging version. When i wrote this answer it was "1.9.22stagging" i install both x86 and x64 wine versions. (again this all done through the playonlinux settings)
4. Through playonLinux settings now access the "wine" tab and click on "configure wine" icon. There you will change the default windows version from Windows XP to Windows Vista. (all other don't seem to work at least not on my PC)
5. Now using PlayonLinux start the LoL launcher (the screen will look weird, however, you should be able to see the League of legends logo on the top left, the percentage and download speed bar on the middle and the settings and minimize icons on the right.
6. This installation takes longer than when using windows.For me using Windows LoL installs in about 2.5 hrs. However, using Ubuntu it took 5 to 6 hours to install. During the installation it might seem like if the installation freezes or your installation stops and your download speed might even reduce to cero for a while but "PLEASE BE PATIENT"
7. Today is November 15, 2016 and i install LoL 6.22 and play.

8.if there is any new patch i would try waiting for the new playonlinux stagging version of wine before removing or changing anything else.